# Updating ReactJS UI with loop data one after another

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have recently created grid in UI and I want to show the complete flow of motion for all the points given by the array. However, the UI was updated with the value in the last loop.
For ex: position = [1, 2, 3]
At the initial point '1', there is a circle
then the circle move to 2 -> then 3

Instead, moving from 1 to 3

Can anybody help me to achieve this?

My whole class is as follows,

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import './style.css';
import Grid from './grid'
class Game extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            idOfBegin: "1",
            position: 0,
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            position: [],
            arrOfObj: [100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91,
                81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90,
                80, 79, 78, 77, 76, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71,
                61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70,
                60, 59, 58, 57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51,
                41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
                40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31,
                21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
                20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11,
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
            ]
        };
    }

    start = () => {
        var a = document.getElementById("3");
        var codinates = a.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = codinates.left + 35;
        var y = codinates.top + 5;
        console.log(x, y);
        this.setState({ xAxis: x });
        this.setState({ yAxis: y });
    }
    loadPosition = async (event) => {
        fetch('api/groups')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                //console.log('======== ' +data);
                //groups.map(group => setPosition(group));
                this.setState({ position: data });
            });
    }
    getCellValue = async (event) => {
        this.loadPosition();
        this.state.position.forEach(p => {
            console.log('====== ' + p);
            if (p != null) {
                var a = document.getElementById(p);
                var codinates = a.getBoundingClientRect();
                var x = codinates.left + 35;
                var y = codinates.top + 5;
                //console.log(x,y);
                this.setState({ xAxis: x });
                this.setState({ yAxis: y });
            }
        });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ xAxis: 45 });
        this.setState({ yAxis: 905 });
    }
 

    render() {
        
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <div className="grid"><Grid arrOfObj={this.state.arrOfObj} />
                                <motion.div animate={{ x: this.state.xAxis, y: this.state.yAxis }}
                                    transition={{ type: "tween", duration: 1 }}
                                ></motion.div>
                            
                            </div>
                            <div className="control">
                                <Button color="primary" onClick={() => this.start()}>Start</Button>
                                <Button color="primary" onClick={() => this.getCellValue()}>Roll Dice</Button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            
                    );
       
    }
}
export default Game;
```